# $(x-y)(f(f(x)^2)-f(f(y)^2))=(f(x)-f(y))(f(x)^2-f(y)^2$

Tags: functional-equations

> Find $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies:
>
> $f\small(0)\normalsize=0, f\small(1)\normalsize=2015. \\
> (x-y)(f\small(f(x)^2\small)\normalsize-f\small(f(y)^2\small)\normalsize)=(f\small(x)\normalsize-f\small(y)\normalsize)(f\small(x)^2\normalsize-f\small(y)^2\normalsize)$

My Attempt:

\begin{align}
&f \not\equiv c. \\
\Rightarrow \; & \color{blue} {\exists \ t_k \text{ s.t. } f(t_k) \neq k.} &  \tag{1} \label{1} \\ 
& \color{red} {\exists y_1, y_2 \text{ s.t. } f(y_1) \neq f(y_2).} \tag{2} \label{2} \\
\ \\
&\text{let } f(a)=f(b), f(x) \neq f(a) \text{ by } \color{red}{(\ref 2)}. \\
P(x, a): \; & (x-a)(f\small(f(x)^2)\normalsize-f(f\small(a)^2\normalsize))=(f(x)-f(a))(f(x)^2-f(a)^2). \\
P(x, b): \; & (x-b)(f\small(f(x)^2)\normalsize-f(f\small(b)^2\normalsize))=(f(x)-f(b))(f(x)^2-f(b)^2). \\
& f(x) \neq f(a), f(x) \neq f(b). \\
\therefore \; & (f(x)-f(a))(f(x)^2-f(a)^2) = (f(x)-f(b))(f(x)^2-f(b)^2) \neq 0. \\
\Rightarrow \; & (x-a)(f\small(f(x)^2)\normalsize-f\small(f(a)^2)\normalsize)=(x-b)(f\small(f(x)^2)\normalsize - f\small(f(b)^2)\normalsize). \\
&  f\small(f(x)^2)\normalsize - f\small(f(a)^2)\normalsize) = f\small(f(x)^2)\normalsize - f\small(f(b)^2)\normalsize) \ \Rightarrow \ x-a=x-b, a=b. \\
\therefore \; & \color{green}{f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b.} \label{3} \tag{3}
\end{align}

Comment: Could you tell the origin of this problem ? A 2015 Olympiad somewhere on the globe ?

Comment: @RamanujanXV $f(x)^2$ means $(f(x))^2$.

Comment: @RamanujanXV My expectation is that $f(x) = 2015x$ or $f(x)=2015 \sqrt{x}.$

Comment: @JeanMarie I just found it on the problem collection, which has collected various kinds of Olympiad Problems.

Comment: Same questions (with $2013$ instead of $2015$) on AOPS: "[(x-y)(f(f^2(x))-f(f^2(y)))=(f(x)-f(y))(f^2(x)-f^2(y))](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1556618p9496902)" and "[function equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h516059p2902445)". I found them using [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cleft(x-y%5Cright)%5Cleft(f%5Cleft(f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5E2%5Cright)-f%5Cleft(f%5Cleft(y%5Cright)%5E2%5Cright)%5Cright)%3D%5Cleft(f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)-f%5Cleft(y%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Cleft(f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5E2-f%5Cleft(y%5Cright)%5E2%5Cright)%24&p=1)

Comment: Please avoid titles that only consist of Mathjax, and edit the current title by adding some text (a parenthesis is also missing). Also, please search before posting, to avoid duplication. Approach Zero works very well for functional equation post on MSE and AOPS. Those aside, one of the AOPS posts linked above suggests that the source is Problem 5 from day 2 of Vietnam Mathematical Olympiad 2013. You can edit your post and add this (after verifying it, if you really want it to be correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted on [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1556618p9496902), and I am posting the arranged solution.

\begin{align}
P(x, y): \; & (x-y)(f(f(x)^2)-f(f(y)^2))=(f(x)-f(y))(f(x)^2-f(y)^2).\\
P(x, 0): \; & xf(f(x)^2)=f(x)^3. \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & yf(f(x)^2)+xf(f(y)^2)=f(x)f(y)(f(x)+f(y)). \text{ (Let this one be $Q(x, y).$)} \\
\ \\
Q(1, 1): \; & f(2015^2)=2015^3. \\
\ \\
Q(1, x): \; & 2015^3x+f(f(x)^2)=2015f(x)(2015+f(x)). \\
Q(x, x): \; & xf(f(x)^2)=f(x)^3. \\
xQ(1, x)-Q(x, x): \; & 2015^3x^2=2015^2xf(x)+2015xf(x)^2-f(x)^3. \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & f(x)^3-(2015x)f(x)^2-(2015^2x)f(x)+2015^3x^2=0. \\
\Rightarrow \; & (f(x)-2015x)(f(x)^2-2015^2x)=0. \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & f(x)=2015x \text{ for } \forall x \leq 0. \ (\because f(x)^2-2015^2x >0.) \\
\ \\
P(x, 0): \; & xf(f(x)^2)=f(x)^3. \\
x<0: \; & xf(2015^2x^2)=2015^3x^3, f(2015^2x^2)=2015^3x^2. \\
\Rightarrow \; & f(x)=2015x \text{ for } \forall x \geq 0. \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & f(x)=2015x.
\end{align}